# Unicode Library

Tags: files

I am currently having "Requirements problem" with Drupal. When I 'Verify requirements' at the start, I get an issue of not being able to continue.

> **Unicode library**
>
> **Multibyte string input conversion in PHP is active and must be disabled. Check the php.ini mbstring.http_input setting. Please refer to the PHP mbstring documentation for more information.**

The Unicode library is the issue.

[image]

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's wrong with it and where to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

Disable multibyte string input conversion either

in your **php.ini** (and reload Apache):

```
mbstring.http_input = pass
mbstring.http_output = pass
```

OR in your **.htaccess** (which already should be there by default, so maybe only your .htaccess is missing):

```
php_value mbstring.http_input pass
php_value mbstring.http_output pass
```

OR in your **settings.php**:

```
ini_set('mbstring.http_input', 'pass');
ini_set('mbstring.http_output', 'pass');
```